# Unable to run windows app using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using visual code to run react native windows app. But i am getting a below given error.

```
....
Build configuration: Debug
Build platform: x86
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1809,3): error MSB4019:
 The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\
WindowsXaml\v12.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Cpp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Impo
rt> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [D:\MobileWorkSpace\RN_Mobile_App\cAp
pTypeScript\node_modules\react-native-windows\Yoga\csharp\Yoga\Yoga.Universal.vcxproj]
Build failed with message Error: Command failed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Profe
ssional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:/MobileWorkSpace/RN_Mobile_App/cAppTypeScript/windows/cAppT
ypeScript.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=quiet /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platf
orm=x86 /p:AppxBundle=Never /p:PlatformToolset=v141 /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0. Check your build configura
tion.
```

Comment: which version of react native?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4

Comment: It looks like your installation of Microsoft C++ compiler is broken (or maybe just different version than expected etc.).

Comment: Yes i excluded UWP C++ compiler while installing Microsoft SDK. Now i am re-installing.

Comment: Same issue...not resolved after re-installation. I had doubt that it is possible to develop react native UWP using visual code or should we use VS 2017?

Comment: Did you try to re-run 'react-native windows' before running 'react-native run-windows'? That fixed it for me. Also, it may be a good thing to try it out from Visual Studio, by opening the project.

Comment: Solved :: I removed the VCTarget path from the environment variables which i given earlier and then it works.